# Why do my arcs end at the wrong node positions?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

I am trying to plot some arcs using tikz and the package tkz-euclide. However, it seems that the arcs do not end at the points where I want them to end. For example, consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,10pt,border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}    % create figures based on Euclidean geometry
\usetkzobj{all}             % load all objects defined by tkz-euclide


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% define the points
\tkzDefPoint(0,1){A}
\tkzDefPoint(1.62,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(0,-1){C}
\tkzCircumCenter(A,B,C)\tkzGetPoint{O}


% print the points
\fill[color=gray] (A) circle [radius=0.05] node[above] {A};
\fill[color=gray] (B) circle [radius=0.05] node[left]  {B}; 
\fill[color=gray] (C) circle [radius=0.05] node[above] {C};
\fill[color=gray] (O) circle [radius=0.05] node[left]  {O};


% print the arcs
\tkzDrawArc[color=green](O,C)(A)
\tkzDrawArc[color=red](O,A)(C)
\tkzDrawArc[color=blue](B,A)(C)
\tkzDrawArc[color=orange](A,C)(B)
\tkzDrawArc[color=black](C,B)(A)


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As shown in the picture, the arcs do not meet in point A and B, (as they should), but in point C (I do not know why it works only there?). What am I doing wrong?[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a typo in the `B`-coordinate. If instead you use

```
\tkzDefPoint(1.732,0){B}
```

then your diagram becomes:

[image]

As `ABC` is an equilateral triangle the real coordinate for `B` is
 `(\sqrt{3),0)\approx(1.732,0)`.

This said, you would be much better off letting tikz do the thinking for you by using polar coordinates:

```
\tkzDefPoint(120:1){A}
\tkzDefPoint(0:1){B}
\tkzDefPoint(240:1){C}
```

Comment: Shouldn't matter though, arc is an arc.

Comment: @percusse It does matter: the arcs drawn by the OP intersect at different points.

Comment: I mean it doesn't have to be a circular arc.

Answer (score 11):

Why doing manual calculations? The problem (which has been explained in other answers) can be easily solved if instead of manual calculations one uses the tools provided by the package, so instead of the error-prone manual calculation of the third vertex `B`:

```
\tkzDefPoint(0,1){A}
\tkzDefPoint(1.62,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(0,-1){C}
```

you should simply use `\tkzDefTriangle` with the `equilateral` option, so the third vertex is automatically (and appropriately calculated):

```
\tkzDefPoint(0,1){A}
\tkzDefPoint(0,-1){C}
\tkzDefTriangle[equilateral](A,C)
\tkzGetPoint{B}
```

The complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,10pt,border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}    % create figures based on Euclidean geometry
\usetkzobj{all}             % load all objects defined by tkz-euclide


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% define the points
\tkzDefPoint(0,1){A}
%\tkzDefPoint(1.62,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(0,-1){C}
\tkzDefTriangle[equilateral](A,C)\tkzGetPoint{B}
\tkzCircumCenter(A,B,C)\tkzGetPoint{O}


% print the points
\fill[color=gray] (A) circle [radius=0.05] node[above] {A};
\fill[color=gray] (B) circle [radius=0.05] node[left]  {B}; 
\fill[color=gray] (C) circle [radius=0.05] node[above] {C};
\fill[color=gray] (O) circle [radius=0.05] node[left]  {O};


% print the arcs
\tkzDrawArc[color=green](O,C)(A)
\tkzDrawArc[color=red](O,A)(C)
\tkzDrawArc[color=blue](B,A)(C)
\tkzDrawArc[color=orange](A,C)(B)
\tkzDrawArc[color=black](C,B)(A)


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

We have to notice that here `arc` is an unfortunate abbreviation because it is actually **a circular arc**.  An elliptical arc is always possible with given two points and two semi-axes. But here the syntax is allowing for only circular ones. Just to prove a point, there is a basic level `\pgpatharcto` command and I quickly hacked a version of it to include in the `\tkzDrawArc` scenarios.

Again, **it is certainly not complete!**

Long story short, as it is, `\tkzDrawArc` only draws circular arcs between two points. If they are not at the same distance from the selected center, then first point distance wins and the circular arc is drawn based on that distance.

```
\documentclass[tikz,10pt,border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}    % create figures based on Euclidean geometry
\usetkzobj{all}             % load all objects defined by tkz-euclide

\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{/drawarc/varying radius/.code= {\global\def\tkz@numa{5}}}
\def\tkzDrawArcV{\pgfutil@ifnextchar[{\tkz@DrawArcV}{\tkz@DrawArcV[]}}
\def\tkz@DrawArc[#1](#2,#3)(#4){% 
\begingroup%
\pgfkeys{/drawarc/.cd,towards,delta=0}% 
\pgfqkeys{/drawarc}{#1}%  
\ifcase\tkz@numa%
   \tkzDrawArcN[#1](#2,#3)(#4)%  
\or% 1
   \tkzDrawArcRotate[#1](#2,#3)(#4)%  
\or% 2
   \tkzDrawArcAngles[#1](#2,#3)(#4)% 
   \or% 3
   \tkzDrawArcRAngles[#1](#2,#3)(#4)%
 \or% 4
   \tkzDrawArcR[#1](#2,#3)(#4)%
 \or% 5
   \tkzDrawArcV[#1](#2,#3)(#4)%
\fi%    
\endgroup%
}

\def\tkz@DrawArcV[#1](#2,#3)(#4){%
\begingroup%
  \tkzCalcLength(#2,#3)\tkzGetLength{tkz@radiusa}%
  \tkzCalcLength(#2,#4)\tkzGetLength{tkz@radiusb}%
  \tkzFindSlopeAngle(#2,#3)\tkzGetAngle{tkz@FirstAngle}%  
  \tkzFindSlopeAngle(#2,#4)\tkzGetAngle{tkz@SecondAngle}%
  \pgfkeys{/tikz/.search also={/drawarc}}%
  \pgf@process{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}}%
  \pgf@process{\pgfpointanchor{#3}{center}}%
\pgfpatharcto{\tkz@radiusa}{\tkz@radiusb}{\tkz@FirstAngle}{0}{1}%{\pgfpoint{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}}%
\pgfusepath{draw}%
\endgroup%
} 


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% define the points
\tkzDefPoint(0,1){A}
\tkzDefPoint(1.62,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(0,-1){C}
\tkzDefPoint(3,1){E}

\tkzCircumCenter(A,B,C)\tkzGetPoint{O}


% print the points
\fill[color=gray] (A) circle [radius=0.05] node[above] {A};
\fill[color=gray] (B) circle [radius=0.05] node[left]  {B}; 
\fill[color=gray] (C) circle [radius=0.05] node[above] {C};
\fill[color=gray] (O) circle [radius=0.05] node[left]  {O};
\fill[color=gray] (E) circle [radius=0.05] node[left]  {E};

% print the arcs
\tkzDrawArc[color=green](O,C)(A)
\tkzDrawArc[color=red](O,A)(C)
\tkzDrawArc[varying radius](B,A)(C)
\tkzDrawArc[varying radius](E,A)(C)
\tkzDrawArc[varying radius](C,B)(A)


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Andrew is totally right. However to answer the questions in you last sentence directly:

> (I do not know why it works only there?). What am I doing wrong?

It works for the arcs `(B,A)(C)` and `(O,A)(C)` and `(O,C)(A)` because B and O have the same distances to A as to C which is needed to draw an arc.

The arcs `(A,C)(B)` and `(C,B)(A)` are just not possible because there is no circle with the center A that hits both C and B as they require different radii.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! I did not recognize the symmetry inherent in the figure.