# Drawing an arc of a circle centered at a point distinct from the origin

Tags: tikz-pgf

I draw an angle of 30 degrees at the origin. The common endpoint of the two line segments comprising this angle is `D` and the other endpoints are `E'` and `F`.  `F` is at a distance of `4` from line segment `DE'`.  I want to draw an arc of a circle centered at F with radius `5`.  This arc should intersect `DE'` at two points.  I don't know what arc is drawn with my code!

What is wrong with the code to make the right-angle mark?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}


% Refer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196181/why-do-my-arcs-end-at-the-wrong-node-positions
% Refer to  http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/intersecting-lines/
% To have TikZ calculate the foot of the altitude of a triangle, see Chapter 13, section 5 in the TikZ manual.


\begin{document}



\noindent {\bf 19.) }In $\triangle{\mathit{DEF}}$,  $\vert DF \vert = 8$, $\vert EF \vert = 5$, and $\angle{\mathit{EDF}} = 30$. How many such triangles are there?
\vskip0.2in

\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}

%These commands draw edges $DF$ and $E'F$ so that $\angle{\mathit{E'DF}} = 30$.
%$DF$ is to be drawn at an angle of 120 degrees and DE' is to be drawn at an
%angle of angle of 150 degrees. Since the length of DE' is not specified, it
%is to be drawn as a ray.
\coordinate (D) at (0,0);
\node (vertex_D) at ($(D) + (-45:7.5pt)$){$D$};
\coordinate (F) at (120:8);
\node (vertex_F) at ($(F) + (90:7.5pt)$){$F$};
\coordinate (E') at (150:12);
\node (vertex_E') at ($(E') + (-90:7.5pt)$){$E'$};
\draw (D) -- (F);
\draw (D) -- (E');

\path pic[draw, angle radius=10mm,"$30$",angle eccentricity=1.25] {angle = F--D--E'};

%These commands label the length of DF.
\coordinate (DF_midpoint) at ($(D)!0.5!(F)$);
\node (DF_midpoint_label) at ($(DF_midpoint) + (30:7.5pt)$) {8};


%These commands draw the height of the triangle from F to line segment $DE'$.
%The height is labeled $h$.
\coordinate (P) at ($(D)!(F)!(E')$);
\draw [dashed] (F) -- (P) node [midway, right]{$h = 4$};
\node (point_P) at ($(P) + (-120:7.5pt)$){$P$};


%These commands draw an arc of a circle centered at F with radius 5.
\draw[dashed,draw=blue!30] (F) arc (150:290:5);

%The following commands make the right-angle mark and "colors" the inside of it white.
\coordinate (U) at ($(P)!4mm!45:(D)$);
\draw (U) -- ($(D)!(U)!(E')$);
\draw (U) -- ($(F)!(U)!(P)$);

\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}
\vskip0.25in

\end{document}
```

Comment: When you write `(F) arc (...)`, `F` is the starting point of the arc, not the center!

Comment: `\draw[dashed] ([shift=(F)]150:5) arc[start angle=150, end angle=290, radius=5];`?

Comment: BTW, `\angle{\mathit{EDF}} = 30` would be an angle of 278.87° because the number 30 misses the degree sign. Also neither `\angle` or `\triangle` are macros with an argument, therefore the braces around `\mathit{...}` are not necessary. `\bf` is deprecated, use `\textbf{...}` instead. Also a space between `19.` and `In` is missing.

Comment: @Heiko Oberdiek   The braces after `angle` and `triangle` are just for me to read the code.  I will have to get in the habit of using `\textbf`.  Is the command for putting text in italics in text mode `textit`?  I edited the post again to include the space after `19.)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An arc doesn't have center specification so you have  a start/end angle and the radius. Also the geometry is not right.

First F is along 120 degree line from D hence you have to place a point relative to that . Here I also move to a point still on the 120 degree line and draw the arc starting from 120 degrees. Had I moved to somewhere else I need to take into account.

I've also commented out your line that makes the right angle problematic. In

[A diagram for an argument to the Pythagorean Theorem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248302/a-diagram-for-an-argument-to-the-pythagorean-theorem)

I've fixed that with a different syntax already.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate[label=-45:$D$] (D) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=90:$F$] (F) at (120:8);
\coordinate[label=-90:$E$] (E) at (150:12);
\draw (F) -- (D) -- (E);
\path pic[draw, angle radius=10mm,"$30$",angle eccentricity=1.25] {angle = F--D--E};
\coordinate[label=45:$8$] (DF_midpoint) at ($(D)!0.5!(F)$);
\coordinate[label=-135:$P$] (P) at ($(D)!(F)!(E)$);
\draw [dashed] (F) -- (P) node [midway, right]{$h = 4$};

\draw[dashed,draw=blue!30] (F) ++(120:5) arc (120:290:5);

\coordinate (U) at ($(P)!4mm!45:(D)$);
%\draw (U) -- ($(D)!(U)!(E)$); % Not necessarily parallel to FP !!!
\draw (U) -- ($(F)!(U)!(P)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: The question text says, that |EF| = 5, then a circle around F with radius = 5 goes through E, which is located at `($(P)!30mm!180:(D)$)`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I am indeed confused about the text hence I just followed the drawing spec instead of the geometry.

Comment: @Heiko Oberdiek I will edit the code so that I have `E'` instead of `E` in the display.  I did not intend to include the problem in my post.

Comment: @percusse  Why does `\draw (U) -- ($(D)!(U)!(E)$);` not necessarily draw a line parallel to `FP`?  `($(D)!(U)!(E)$)` is a point through `U` that is perpendicular to line segment `DE`. Since `DE` is perpendicular to `FP`, the small line segment drawn using `\draw (U) -- ($(D)!(U)!(E)$);` should be parallel to `FP`.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're loading the `tkz-euclide` package, you can specify the center (the tikz `arc` command does not specify a center), using

```
\tkzDrawArc[R, color=blue,dashed,thick](F, 5cm)(135,315)
```

- `F` is the center.
- `5cm` is the radius.
- The last two numbers are the starting and the ending polar coordinates, respectively.
- Lastly, `R` is an option (from fr. *rayon*, radius), where you can specify the center and then a  radius.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}


% Refer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196181/why-do-my-arcs-end-at-the-wrong-node-positions
% Refer to  http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/intersecting-lines/
% To have TikZ calculate the foot of the altitude of a triangle, see Chapter 13, section 5 in the TikZ manual.


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

%These commands draw edges $DF$ and $E'F$ so that $\angle{\mathit{E'DF}} = 30$.
%$DF$ is to be drawn at an angle of 120 degrees and DE' is to be drawn at an
%angle of angle of 150 degrees. Since the length of DE' is not specified, it
%is to be drawn as a ray.
\coordinate (D) at (0,0);
\node (vertex_D) at ($(D) + (-45:7.5pt)$){$D$};
\coordinate (F) at (120:8);
\node (vertex_F) at ($(F) + (90:7.5pt)$){$F$};
\coordinate (E') at (150:12);
\node (vertex_E') at ($(E') + (-90:7.5pt)$){$E'$};
\draw (D) -- (F);
\draw (D) -- (E');

\path pic[draw, angle radius=10mm,"$30$",angle eccentricity=1.25] {angle = F--D--E'};

%These commands label the length of DF.
\coordinate (DF_midpoint) at ($(D)!0.5!(F)$);
\node (DF_midpoint_label) at ($(DF_midpoint) + (30:7.5pt)$) {8};


%These commands draw the height of the triangle from F to line segment $DE'$.
%The height is labeled $h$.
\coordinate (P) at ($(D)!(F)!(E')$);
\draw [dashed] (F) -- (P) node [midway, right]{$h = 4$};
\node (point_P) at ($(P) + (-120:7.5pt)$){$P$};

%These commands draw an arc of a circle centered at F with radius 5.
%\draw[dashed,draw=blue!30] (F) arc (150:290:5);
\tkzDrawArc[R,color=blue,dashed, thick](F, 5)(125,315)

%The following commands make the right-angle mark and "colors" the inside of it white.
\coordinate (U) at ($(P)!4mm!45:(D)$);
\draw (U) -- ($(D)!(U)!(E')$);
\draw (U) -- ($(F)!(U)!(P)$);

\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}
\vskip0.25in

\end{document}
```

Comment: I was careless in loading `tkz-euclide`.  I want to make the right-angle mark just using `TikZ`.  By the way, I was also careless with using `E`.  I replaced `E` in the `TikZ` picture with `E'`.  (You can copy the code from my post ... if you want.)  Why isn't my code making a right-angle mark?  Percusse says that `\draw (U) -- ($(D)!(U)!(E)$);` does not necessarily draw a line parallel to `FP`.

Comment: @user74973 Well, to be fair `tkz-euclide` adds some nice things that it's harder to accomplish with regular Tikz. For example you can also draw a parallel line to another one fairly easy. No problem about `E'`, I'll fix it.

Comment: @user74973 Ah yes, that is not parallel. You can use `tkz-euclide` again for this but maybe you don't want to use the package.

Comment: I am trying to familiarize myself with `TikZ`, as you can surmise from my many posts.

Comment: Do you know why `\draw (U) -- ($(D)!(U)!(E)$);` does not necessarily draw a line parallel to `FP`?  I read that `$(D)!(U)!(E)$` is a point through `U` that is perpendicular to line segment `DE`.  Since `DE` is perpendicular to `FP`, the small line segment drawing using  `\draw (U) -- ($(D)!(U)!(E)$);` should be parallel to `FP`.

Comment: @user74973 It probably depends on how you define `U`, although I'm not very familiar with that particular command. :D

Comment: I have to replace `\draw (U) -- ($(D)!(U)!(E')$);` with `\draw (U) -- ($(P)!(U)!(D)$);`.  If you are interested, see "The Syntax for Projection Modifiers" in the `pgfplots` manual.